# Getting problem while merging rows according to one employee has multiple data in rows

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I am generating family details report using Apache poi. Suppose one employee have multiple family members so I am trying to merge employee cell's row based on family members' row but I am unable to do it

Row row = sheet.createRow(2);

```
     int num = employeeFamilyDTOList.size() + 1;

      Cell c1 = row.createCell((short) 0); sheet.addMergedRegion(new
      CellRangeAddress(2, num, 0, 0));
      c1.setCellValue("employeeFamilyDTO.getEmpCode()");

      Cell c2 = row.createCell((short) 1); sheet.addMergedRegion(new
      CellRangeAddress(2, num, 1, 1));
      c2.setCellValue("employeeFamilyDTO.getEmpName()");
```

public static Workbook familyDetailsReportWriter(List employeeFamilyDTOList,
            Object[] newColumns) {

```
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

    // Create a Sheet
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Family Details");

    // Create a Font for styling header cells
    Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
    headerFont.setBold(true);
    headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
    headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

    Font rowFont = workbook.createFont();
    rowFont.setBold(true);
    rowFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
    rowFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

    // Create a CellStyle with the font
    CellStyle headerCellStyle1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
    headerCellStyle1.setFont(headerFont);
    headerCellStyle1.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    headerCellStyle1.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
```

//      headerCellStyle1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.FINE_DOTS);

```
    CellStyle headerCellStyle2 = workbook.createCellStyle();
    headerCellStyle2.setFont(headerFont);
    headerCellStyle2.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    headerCellStyle2.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    headerCellStyle2.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.FINE_DOTS);

    CellStyle rowCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    rowCellStyle.setFont(rowFont);

    // Create Cell Style for formatting Date
    CellStyle dateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));

    int col = newColumns.length - 1;
    // creating row
    Row headerRow0 = sheet.createRow(0);
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, col));
    Cell cell0 = headerRow0.createCell(0);
    cell0.setCellValue("Family Details of All Employees");
    cell0.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle1);

    Row headerRow1 = sheet.createRow(1);
    // Creating cells
    for (int i = 0; i < newColumns.length; i++) {
        Cell cell = headerRow1.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(newColumns[i].toString());
        cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle2);
    }

    /*
     * Row row = sheet.createRow(2);
     * 
     * int num = employeeFamilyDTOList.size() + 1;
     * 
     * Cell c1 = row.createCell((short) 0); sheet.addMergedRegion(new
     * CellRangeAddress(2, num, 0, 0));
     * c1.setCellValue("employeeFamilyDTO.getEmpCode()");
     * 
     * Cell c2 = row.createCell((short) 1); sheet.addMergedRegion(new
     * CellRangeAddress(2, num, 1, 1));
     * c2.setCellValue("employeeFamilyDTO.getEmpName()");
     */

    int rowNum = 2;

    if (employeeFamilyDTOList != null) {
        for (EmployeeFamilyDTO employeeFamilyDTO : employeeFamilyDTOList) {

             Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            for(int j = 0; j < employeeFamilyDTOList.size()-1; j++) {

                int num = employeeFamilyDTOList.size() + 1;

                Cell c1 = row.createCell((short) 0);
                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2, num, 0, 0));//1145
                c1.setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getEmpCode());

                Cell c2 = row.createCell((short) 1);
                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2, num, 1, 1));
                c2.setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getEmpName());
                break;
            }
            // row.createCell(0).setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getEmpCode());
            // row.createCell(1).setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getEmpName());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getName());
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getRelation());
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getQualificationId());
            row.createCell(5).setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getOccupations());

            Cell datePSIssue = row.createCell(6);
            datePSIssue.setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getDob());
            datePSIssue.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);

            row.createCell(7).setCellValue(employeeFamilyDTO.getContactMobile());

        }
    }

    // Resize all columns to fit the content size
    for (int i = 0; i < newColumns.length; i++) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
    return workbook;
}
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add merged region A3:A4 to sheet because it overlaps with an existing merged region (A3:A4).
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.validateMergedRegions(XSSFSheet.java:480)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.addMergedRegion(XSSFSheet.java:413)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.addMergedRegion(XSSFSheet.java:367)
        at com.csipl.hrms.common.util.EmployeeExcelWriter.familyDetailsReportWriter(EmployeeExcelWriter.java:1145)
        at com.csipl.hrms.report.controller.EmployeeReportController.FamilyDetailsReport(EmployeeReportController.java:272)

Comment: Can you show us the line 1145 of `EmployeeExcelWriter`? It seems there is a duplicate merge call...

Comment: I have edited my question you can check on comment 1145 line

Comment: Is it the block comment? I guess so, it uses `addMergedRegion(...)`. You will have to debug your code in order to find the bug.